# How to show that the function $g(x)=x|\sin(x^{-1/2})|$ is absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am having trouble showing the on $[0,1]$, $g(x):=x\mid\sin(x^{-1/2})\ \mid$ when $x>0$ and $0$ is $x=0$ is absolutely continuous. I was instructed to try:  $\ m(A) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_{A} f < \epsilon$, but I am not sure how.

Comment: I looked at your [list of questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/68477/rod?tab=questions&sort=newest)... please work on your titles. The key words like "measure theory" are expressed by tags; the title should describe the specific problem. It's okay for the title to be a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function  is absolutely continuous if and only if it is an antiderivative of some integrable function (this is the approach via measure theory, which I assume is what you want: it connects to the property $\ m(A) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_{A} f < \epsilon$ that you mentioned).

Given $g(x)=x|\sin(x^{-1/2})|$, you can find it's differentiable everywhere except for a particular countable set $C$, and on each interval of the complement of $C$ its derivative is $$g'(x) =\pm\left( \sin(x^{-1/2})  - \frac12 x^{-1/2}\cos(x^{-1/2})\right)$$ where $\pm$ is constant within the interval. Thus, $|g'(x)|\le 1+\frac12 x^{-1/2}$, which is integrable. Even though $g'$ is not defined at the points of $C$, the integral $\int_0^x g'(x)\,dx$ still makes sense as a Lebesgue integral, and gives the value of $g(x)$ (note that $g'$ integrates to zero over every component of the complement of $C$).

Comment: I just can't show or really argue that the $C$ is in fact countable.

Comment: By $C$ I mean the set $\{0\}\cup \{x: \sin(x^{-1/2})=0\}$. You know when sine turns into $0$, right? Note that $C$ is closed. So, every point not in $C$ has a neighborhood in which sine is not zero, hence $g$ is differentiable in that neighborhood.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah and those zeros are countable. Thanks a lot.